What is needed to make this abstract idea patentable
This is an idea for the payment system of an app:
If (A) and (B) occurs, then the user will pay the app.

Assume that it is novel and non-obvious.
What might be some implementation details needed to make the idea an actual invention rather than just an idea.

Algorithm and business method patents often require very specific claim language to avoid being considered abstract. You really may want to consult with an actual patent attorney with experience in such patents if you want to end up with an effective patent.
